# How to replace setCallbackHandler() with a Sync call rather than Async?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I have a problem with some Javascript where I set off a setCallbackHandler() and I need it to complete prior to continuing through the rest of my code. Below is an example, by the time I get to my alert(count) the setCallbackHandler is still processing.

I believe I need to have a Sync call rather than an Async, but I haven't had any luck implementing any... Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
    function checkPerson(r){
        if(r){
        count++
        }
        else{
        alert("None Found");
        }
    }


    var g = new cfc_method();
    g.setCallbackHandler(checkPerson);
    g.returnIds(user_id);

alert(count);
```

Comment: is this only related to javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any code that must run after the request completes should be in the callback handler. I would not recommend changing cfajax calls to sync, however, if you must, you can call `g.setSyncMode()` to set the call mode to synchronous. Note that in synchronous mode, the data is returned directly from the cfc method call, not to the callback handler.

Comment: This is what worked fore me: Thanks!

var g = new cfc_method(); 
g.setSyncMode() 
var theResult = g.returnIds(user_id); 

    function checkPerson(theResult){ 
        if(theResult){ 
        count++ 
        } 
        else{ 
        alert("None Found"); 
        } 
    }